# Изменение input'a переменной из PHP через JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Необходимо заменить текст input'a текущей датой, получаемой из PHP.
Вот код, при нажатии input заполняется как undefined. Где ошибка?

PHP:

```
$today = getdate();
$nowdate = $today['mday']." ".$today['month']." ".$today['year']."   ".$today['hours'].":".$today['minutes'].":".$today['seconds'];
```

HTML:

```
<button style="margin-top:3px" onclick="current(<?php $nowdate ?>)">Текущая</button>
```

JS:

```
function current(el) {
document.getElementById('date').value = el;
}
```

Comment: Надо выводить переменную либо `<?php echo $nowdate; ?>` либо `<?= $nowdate; ?>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оба варианта ничего не дали. теперь форма не заполняется вовсе

Comment: А так `onclick="current('<?php echo $nowdate; ?>')"` ? то есть конструкцию `php` поместить в кавычки. Ибо это же строка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский уже думал на эту тему. вместо undefined выдает просто пустой input

Comment: А у вас случаем и `php` и `html` не в одном файле находятся? При этом код `php` ниже, чем данный `html`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский php и html в одном php файле, но php код выше, чем html

Comment: Тогда, возможно, лучше поместить весь файл с кодом (надеюсь он не гигантский) в описание... чтоб можно было взглянуть. А то чакра экстрасенса иссякла)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский http://pastebin.com/dQ4kuE42

Comment: Где-то ошибка в одном из других мест. возможно связанное с `mysql`. Если их убрать - то все отображает и работает, как я описал выше. Если сделать `onclick="current('<?php echo $nowdate; ?>')"` и  в консоли браузера посмотреть ошибки. там что-то есть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, спасибо, все работает. проблема была в js, который не использовался.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: Опубликовал как ответ. Можно отметить как правильный)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отобразить переменную `php` в коде, нужно использовать `echo` или конструкцию вида `<?=  ?>`, которая является сокращением от `echo`.

Т.е. переменную необходимо выводить так: `<?php echo $nowdate; ?>`  или так `<?=  $nowdate; ?>`

Так как в вашем случае это значение строковое, то его нужно выводить в кавычках. Следовательно обработчик `onclick` будет выглядеть так: `onclick="current('<?php echo $nowdate; ?>')"`

Также, если `php` код и `html` располагаются в одном файле, то код `php` должен находится выше представленного `html`

Для контроля ошибок всегда можно использовать консоль браузера. Если в коде имеется `javascript`, то на некоторые ошибки в коде он реагирует отказом в работе. Соответственно, узнать причину можно открыв консоль и посмотреть причину ошибки. Как правило Она указывает на место в коде, где произошла ошибка и причину.